# How to run a scheduled job on Azure?

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I am planning to create a service that checks something on a website with an interval. Compares the results with the DB and sends a email out if changes has been made.
No user interface is needed.

What type of service should I use for this type of application?

Comment: This type of question is off-topic (very broad, opinion-soliciting, service/tool recommendation) for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no single correct answer to your question. If you want to keep things really lightweight, you could use an Azure Function App with a [timer trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer).

If the Function App model isn't right for you, you can deploy a [scheduled Web Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs#CreateScheduledCRON) to an App Service deployment.

For some scenarios, the best alternative is a virtual machine with cron / Windows Task Scheduler. For others, it's to write an app that comes with its own scheduler.

Comment: Why even answer? You know it's off-topic (very broad, opinion-soliciting, service recommendation). And there's no possible way to give an objective, correct, reusable answer here. And your answer contains multiple suggestions, none of them definitive/objective/correct.

Comment: Well, I figured that I could at least list some of the services that are suitable for this purpose. I think "soliciting for recommendations of a service" is a bit of a blunt hammer for these cases, given that in some cases, different Azure services are more like different NuGet packages for the same thing than like different SaaS services for the same use case.

Comment: I mean, in my opinion, if you just reword the title to "how to run a scheduled job on Azure", the tone of the whole thing changes significantly.

Comment: And yes, I just now realized that I'm arguing with a Microsoft Senior Azure architect. :P

Comment: Nope - I'm not arguing. And I would've responded the same way with any other question regarding any other cloud (or any other broadstroke question like it) - has nothing to do with my employer or position. And no, your edit to the title does not change anything.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but it _was_ ironic. I'll concede the point, but to take this to a more productive direction, suppose the gist of the question was "I want to do X on Azure, what are my options?" -- what would your preferred forum be? Asking out of genuine curiosity. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to look at [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/functions/). That is probably the simplest thing you can do and it can run on timer. That seems quite relevant to your use case.

> Azure Functions supports an event based on a
>   timer using Cron job syntax. For example, execute code that runs every
>   15 minutes and clean up a database table based on customised business
>   logic.

Comment: Please don't answer such off-topic, very broad questions. There's no possible "right" answer to be had. Nothing reusable, or objective.